# Does Visual Studio have a text editor formatting setting for the spacing in generic type parameter lists?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, settings

It seems Visual Studio has a setting under ***Text Editor >> (language) >> Formatting*** for practically everything.  However, I've never been able to find one for generic type parameter lists and the default format for these is not to my liking.

Visual Studio automatically formats them to be like this:

```
Dictionary<int,string> myDictionary;
```

I am looking for a setting to enforce this formatting instead (notice the space):

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary;
```

**EDIT:**

This problem is mostly, if not entirely, experienced when accepting Intellisense's suggestion for a type.  Any space I type is not removed.  For example, I will often type initializers by declaring a field then adding " = new " and then I hit the TAB key to accept the default constructor that Intellisense suggests.  In the case of the Dictionary I mentioned above, this would result in the following code being created:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

The first parameter list is what I manually typed and so it has the space.  The second is what Intellisense inserts for me, and it does not have a space.  I am hoping to find a way to automatically get that space in there.

Comment: Have you checked out Text Editor>C#>Formatting>Spacing>Set spacing for delimiters>Insert space after comma?

Comment: @Logarr - I do have that checked.  I should point out that the problem is mostly present when Intellisense completely generates the parameter list such as when typing "new" and then hitting TAB to accept the constructor that it suggests.  It doesn't remove the space when I type it myself.  I will edit my question to show this.

Comment: try formatting the code afterward using ctrl-k ctrl-d just to see if @Logarr suggestion reformat's what the expansion template inserted when you pressed tab.  I am curious if that fixes it...

Comment: Resharper does this through live templates and I am not sure that visual studio does this without a tool like resharper or coderush.

Comment: @phillip - I hadn't ever used the ctrl+ k, > ctrl + d shortcut.  It worked perfectly.  How strange that Intellisense automatically inserts an improperly formatted parameter list, different than even the formatting shown in MSDN's own examples.  Is there maybe a way to edit the template Intellisense uses to do this?

Comment: @bubbleking Usually, visual studio will reformat the section of code (based on your settings) when you hit enter.  So it will initially be formatted how you described but when you hit enter then it updates that block.

Comment: @phillip - Ah, so then, are you saying because it is not doing that for me in this instance that I have something misconfigured, or that VS has a bug, or that it simply falls short when it comes to this particular situation (generic type parameter lists)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69752/discussion-between-phillip-and-bubbleking).